# How to open callouts for React Native Maps markers upon loading

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-maps

I  want all the callouts for all the markers to be opened upon mounting the screen component. Currently, it only opens only when it's clicked on the marker. How do I use useRef in a functional component to do this?

```
const markerRef = useRef(React.createRef)

return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
        <MapView 
            style={{ flex: 1 }} 
            region={region}
            onRegionChangeComplete={onRegionChangeComplete}
        >
            {data && data.posts.map(marker => (
                <Marker
                    ref={markerRef}
                    key={marker.id}
                    coordinate={{latitude: marker.latitude, longitude: marker.longitude }}    
                >
                    <Callout>
                        <Text>{marker.title}</Text>
                        <Text>{JSON.stringify(marker.price)}</Text>
                    </Callout>
                </Marker>
            ))}
        </MapView>
        <View style={styles.inputContainer}> 
            <Icon name="magnify" size={30} color="lightgrey" />
            <TextInput 
                placeholder="Search Term"
                style={styles.input}
                onChangeText={setSearch}
                value={search}
                returnKeyType="search"
                onSubmitEditing={handleSubmit}
            />
        </View>
    </View>
```

When I `console.log(markerRef.current)`, it doesn't provide the `showCallout()` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cleanest way is to create your own view as a marker.
[Arbitrary React Views as Markers](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-maps#arbitrary-react-views-as-markers)

You can see an example of the marker [here](https://github.com/react-native-maps/react-native-maps/blob/master/example/src/examples/PriceMarker.tsx).
And here is an example of it used [here](https://github.com/react-native-maps/react-native-maps/blob/master/example/src/examples/ViewsAsMarkers.tsx).

This is just a start. You could put your own click handler on the marker and hide it.

So, this is probably less ideal, but might work as a hack.
Start with a rendering function.

```
renderCallout() {
    if(this.state.calloutIsRendered === true) return;
    this.setState({calloutIsRendered: true});
    this.markerRef.showCallout();
}
```

Then add it to the onRegionChangeComplete event.

```
<MapView
  onRegionChangeComplete={() => this.renderCallout()}
  ...
>
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm actually trying to utilize `useRef` in a functional component. I can't seem to access the `showCallout()` method using the hook

Comment: I am getting an error 'Cannot read property showCallout' of undefined.

Comment: https://github.com/react-native-maps/react-native-maps/blob/master/example/src/examples/ViewsAsMarkers.tsx

Answer (score 1):

### I have done in this way

in parent component

```
<Marker_List_Start coordinate_start={Here I am passing coordinates and descriptions}/>
```

in child component

```
export default class Marker_List_Start extends Component {
  show = () => {
    this.marker2.showCallout();
  };

  hide = () => {
    this.marker2.hideCallout();
  };

 componentDidUpdate(previousProps,prevState){
if(previousProps.coordinate_start!=this.props.coordinate_start){
    this.hide()
}

 }

  render() {
    const {coordinate_start} = this.props;
    return (
      <>
        <Marker
          ref={ref => {
            this.marker2 = ref;
          }}
          coordinate={coordinate_start}
            //  title={coordinate_start.hole}
            //     description={coordinate_start.description}
          onPress={() => {
            this.show();
          }}>
          <Callout>
            <Text style={{fontWeight: 'bold', color: '#000'}}>
              {coordinate_start.description}
            </Text>
          </Callout>
        </Marker>
      </>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using react functional components.

```
const ExodusMapMarker = ({ branch, key, forwardedRef, selectedBranchName }) => {
  const [calloutVisible, setCalloutVisible] = useState(false);
  const markerRef = useRef(forwardedRef);

  const showCallout = () => {
    markerRef.current?.showCallout();
  };

  const hideCallout = () => {
    markerRef.current?.hideCallout();
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const selectedBranch = branch?.saccoBranchName === selectedBranchName;
    if (calloutVisible || selectedBranch) {
      hideCallout();
      setTimeout(() => {
        showCallout();
      }, 500);
    }
    console.log('branch', branch);
    console.debug('ref', forwardedRef);
  }, [calloutVisible, branch]);

  const { colors } = useTheme();

  return (
    <Marker
      key={key}
      coordinate={{
        latitude: branch.latitude,
        longitude: branch.longitude,
      }}
      ref={markerRef}
      onPress={() => setCalloutVisible(true)}
      title={branch.saccoBranchName}
      description={branch.telPhone}
    >
      <View
        style={[
          styles.marker,
          {
            backgroundColor: parseHexTransparency(colors.primary, 30),
          },
        ]}
      >
        <Icon name="location-outline" size={20} color={colors.primary} />
      </View>
      <Callout tooltip={true} style={{ width: 'auto' }}>
        <View style={[styles.item, { alignContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center', backgroundColor: '#fff' }]}>
          <CardList
            style={{
              width: 300,
              paddingVertical: 5,
            }}
            onPress={() => {}}
            title={branch.saccoBranchName}
            subtitle={branch.telPhone}
          />
        </View>
      </Callout>
    </Marker>
  );
};


export default Page = () => {
 const  branch = {"latitude": 0.3755, "latitudeDelta": 0.009, "longitude": 32.61123, "longitudeDelta": 0.004, "saccoBranchId": 18, "saccoBranchName": "UPF EXODUS SACCO HQ", "telPhone": "+256 70"};
 return (<View style={{ height: '100%', width: '100%' }}>
              <MapView
                provider={PROVIDER_GOOGLE}
                style={styles.map}
                region={closestBranch}
              >
                  <ExodusMapMarker
                    key={index}
                    branch={branch}
                    selectedBranchName={closestBranch.saccoBranchName}
                    forwardedRef={(markerRef) => (refArray.current[index] = markerRef)}
                  />
              </MapView>
            </View>
  );
}
```