# react-native-maps callout content not updated on change

Tags: react-native, react-native-maps

I am trying to update the content of a `<Callout>` tag on a google maps view using the [react-native-maps](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-maps) npm package. I would like to dynamically load extra content after a map marker is pressed. I have simplified my code to the example below:-

I have already tried using the `tracksInfoWindowChanges` attribute on the marker, and the `showCallout()` method to attempt to manually trigger a re-render. I am using android so the iOS only options such as `redrawCallout()` method are not available.

```
const MyMap = (props) => {
    const [marker, setMarker] = useState({});

    return (
        <MapView
            showsUserLocation
            zoomControlEnabled={true}
            zoomEnabled={true}
            region={{
                latitude: 0,
                longitude: 0,
                latitudeDelta: 0.03,
                longitudeDelta: 0.03,
            }}>
            <Marker
                coordinate={{latitude: 0, longitude: 0}}
                onPress={(e) => {
                    setMarker({ title: 'Test'});           
                }}>
                 <View>
                     <Icon name='key' size={40} color='#384963'</Icon> 
                 </View>
                 <Callout>
                    <Text>{marker.title}</Text>              
                 </Callout>
             </Marker>
        </MapView>
    );
}
```

Is it possible to trigger a re-render of the content after the Callout has been rendered once? From debugging I can see that the component renders after I update my marker state, however the content is not visible until I manually close the Callout and re-opened it.

Comment: Here is the link. I have done in this way. https://stackoverflow.com/a/76160842/14448694

Answer (score 1):

I am having the exact same problem. The suggestion for android, as per [this issue](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-maps/issues/486), is to use `showCallout()`. Below is my work-around for this issue using `showCallout()`:

```js
const MyMap = (props) => {
    const [marker, setMarker] = useState({});
    let markerRef = useRef(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        if (markerRef.current) {
            markerRef.current.showCallout();
        }
    })

    return (
        <MapView
            showsUserLocation
            zoomControlEnabled={true}
            zoomEnabled={true}
            region={{
                latitude: 0,
                longitude: 0,
                latitudeDelta: 0.03,
                longitudeDelta: 0.03,
            }}>
            <Marker
                ref={markerRef}
                coordinate={{latitude: 0, longitude: 0}}
                onPress={(e) => {
                    setMarker({title: `Test ${Math.floor(Math.random() * 10)}`});         
                }}>
                 <View>
                     <Icon name='key' size={40} color='#384963' /> 
                 </View>
                 <Callout>
                    <Text>{marker.title}</Text>              
                 </Callout>
             </Marker>
        </MapView>
    );
}
```

Briefly, I added a `markerRef` and call `markerRef.current.showCallout()` in `useEffect()`. What this achieves, if I am not mistaken, is that each time `MyMap` gets re-rendered, the callout will be forced to show again. I also changed the `onPress` such that the effect of callout re-rendering is more apparent.

Note 1: Each time the marker is pressed, the callout shall have its text updated.

Note 2: If you have multiple markers and callouts, and you want to update only the callout that is currently in view, you will have to add another check in `useEffect()`. Something like: `if (markerRef.current && selectedMarker === 'markerID')` to make sure that only the desired callout is re-rendered continuously.